How to organize rendering multiple images from the same collection of objects?
I have made a model of a house consisting of multiple objects, like the roof, windows, different walls, the terrain etc. (You can assume it's just a number of cubes.)
Now I'd like to render static images from different camera angles, with different sets of objects visible, and with different colors (i.e. materials) in different scenes, to highlight certain objects.
I'd like to be "automatize" the setup, so I can re-render all images when e.g. changing a small detail. So far I've more or less managed to do this by making a sequence of frames in the timeline and keyframing all those properties (visibility, color, camera angle) that change. This works, but it seems not very elegant.
Is there a better suited tool in blender to do the same thing?

one way doing that is using view layers. By copying the view layer, you can change the render visibility easily, if you add all objects in a collection which should be rendered in one image. You can add your different cameras to the scene instead of keyframing them and using markers -> bind camera to marker to change your cameras automatically

@Chris Thank you for the tips! I was not aware of the view layers, they already help so much. By markers you mean the markers we use on the timeline?

exactly! that's what i meant

Thank you very much for the tips, I'll try that! In the meantime thanks to your mention of the view layers, I also discovered that you can use scenes that seem to directly allow choosing different cameras, and we can reuse the same objects/settings by using Scene -> Linked Copy.
